# Notice: Use of undefined constant date - assumed 'date' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\admin\includes\add_post.php on line 14

Tags: php, mysql, post

> Notice: Use of undefined constant date - assumed 'date' in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\admin\includes\add_post.php on line 14
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'd-m-y' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\admin\includes\add_post.php on line 14
>
> Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\admin\includes\add_post.php on line 23
> QUERY FAILED .

```
if (isset($_POST['create_post'])){
    $post_title = $_POST['title'];
    $post_author = $_POST['author'];
    $post_category_id= $_POST['post_category_id'];
    $post_status = $_POST['post_status'];
    
    $post_image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $post_image_temp = $_FILES['image'] ['tmp_name'];

    $post_tags = $_POST['post_tags'];
    $post_content = $_POST['post_content'];
    $post_date = date['d-m-y'];
    $post_comment_count = 4;
 
    move_uploaded_file($post_image_temp, "../images/$post_image");

    $query ="INSERT INTO posts(post_category_id, post_title, post_author, post_date, post_image, post_content, post_tags, post_comment_count, post_status) ";

    $query .="VALUES ({$post_category_id}, '{$post_title}', '{$post_author}',getDate() , '{$post_image}', '{$post_content}', '{$post_tags}', '{$post_comment_count}', '{$post_status}') ";

    $create_post_query = mysqli_error($connection, $query);

    confirmQuery($create_post_query);

 }

?>
```

Comment: `$post_date = date['d-m-y'];` you forgot the dollar sign!

Comment: $post_date = date['d-m-y']; should be  date('Y-m-d') for mysql or simply date('d-m-y') to display any where

Answer (score 1):

**Changes:**

1. It should be `date('d-m-y')`
2. Use `now()` instead of `getDate()`
3. Use `mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error($myConnection));`

**Correct code:**

```
if (isset($_POST['create_post'])){
    $post_title = $_POST['title'];
    $post_author = $_POST['author'];
    $post_category_id= $_POST['post_category_id'];
    $post_status = $_POST['post_status'];

    $post_image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $post_image_temp = $_FILES['image'] ['tmp_name'];

    $post_tags = $_POST['post_tags'];
    $post_content = $_POST['post_content'];
    $post_date = date('d-m-y');
    $post_comment_count = 4;

    move_uploaded_file($post_image_temp, "../images/$post_image");

    $query ="INSERT INTO posts(post_category_id, post_title, post_author, post_date, post_image, post_content, post_tags, post_comment_count, post_status) ";

    $query .="VALUES ({$post_category_id}, '{$post_title}', '{$post_author}',now() , '{$post_image}', '{$post_content}', '{$post_tags}', '{$post_comment_count}', '{$post_status}') ";

    $create_post_query = mysqli_error($connection, $query);

    confirmQuery($create_post_query);

 }

?>
```